# ignoring blank file upload field

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I've a form with upload field, it works fine. it uploads and everything is good, except that when the upload field is empty. the field in the database table goes blank as well, nothing in it, not even the old image entry!

**My Form:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br> 
E-mail: <input type="text" name = "email"><br> 
Phone: <input type="text" name = "phone"><br> 
Photo: <input type="file" name="site_logo"><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Add"> 
</form>
```

**The PHP code:**

```
<?php
    $target = "../upload/";
    $target = $target . basename($_FILES['site_logo']['name']);?>

<?php
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['site_logo']['tmp_name'], $target);
  // output a list of the fields that had errors
     if (!empty($errors)) {
       echo "<p class=\"errors\">";
       echo "Please review the following fields:<br />";

          foreach($errors as $error) {
       echo " - " . $error . "<br />";
   }
       echo "</p>";
       }
?>
```

the query:

```
$site_logo=($_FILES['site_logo']['name']);


                $query = "UPDATE ss_settings SET 
                            site_logo = '{$site_logo}'
                        WHERE id = 1 ";
                $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
```

I've set the database connection and the update query and everything. just posted the process code so it be clear to you guys. I just want it to do nothing when the field is empty.

Comment: So why not implement an `if empty` function to prevent it to go any further?

Comment: i've tried to do so, not working.
can you write the code ? maybe i did it wrong

Comment: If you use the same form for for example edits to the textual data and a file upload is not required, you should post your database code; how you build the query as the problem is there.

Comment: Hi, Becarefore before entering data to database , you should check whether input is present by using js valiadtionand checking whether post/get data is present on page i.e check isset and empty condition

Answer (score 1):

Check out the error messages explained http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

To check if a file wasn't uploaded:

`if ($_FILES['site_logo']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)`

A better way, is to check if there were no errors.

`if ($_FILES['site_logo']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)`

Answer (score 0):

If your query is an UPDATE statement you should not change it, also you can try with

```
<?php
// ...
if($_FILES['site_logo']['name'] == NULL){
   // do stuff when no file field is set
}else{
   // do stuff when file is set
}
// ...
?>
```

Comment: it didn't work, can you write the whole code ? maybe i did a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not use an un-sanitized name for a file, but all you need to do in your case, is check for a valid file-upload before you do your query.

So something like (in [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated):

```
// first line borrowed from @DaveChen, +1 for that
if ($_FILES['site_logo']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
  $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `ss_settings` SET 
                            `site_logo` = :site_logo
                        WHERE `id` = :id ";

  // bind variables
  $stmt->bindValue(':site_logo', $_FILES['site_logo']['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue(':id', $the_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

  // execute query
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try something like this to prevent processing of blank uploads:

```
if($_FILES['site_logo']['error']==0) { 
  // process 
} else { 
  // handle the error 
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you're simply assuming that a successful upload has taken place. **NEVER** assume success. ALways check for failure. PHP provides the `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason. use it:

```
if ($_FILES['site_logo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   ... upload was successful
} else { 
   die("Upload failed with error code: " . $_FILES['site_logo']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are defined here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

You'll wan to check for code 4 (`UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`), which means the user didn't upload anything at all.

Comment: It's not really "check for failure", it's assume failure and check for success.